# Socket.io: receive event triggering multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, callback, socket.io

I'm trying to implement a simple lock using the following code:

Server:

```
socket.on('lock', function(ressInfo) 
{
  var lock = false;
  if(ressLocks.indexOf(ressInfo.id) === -1)
  {
    ressLocks.push(ressInfo.id);
    lock = true;
  }
  socket.emit("lock", lock);
});
```

Client:

```
this.requestLock = function(ressInfo, callback)
{
  if(currentlyOnline)
  {
    socket.emit("lock", ressInfo);

    socket.on("lock", function(lock) 
    {
      // this gets triggered one additional time with each lock
      callback(lock);
    });
  }
  else
  {
    callback(true);
  }
}
```

On the first call I get one callback with `true`, on the second call I get two callbacks with `false`, on the third call three, etc.

What is happening here? Why does `socket.on` get called multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two reasons:

Client side:

- If you are registering for lock function multiple time

Server side:

- As i assume this happens if you are registering multiple times to listen to the events assuming that you are running the socket.on function everytime you recieve events

Heres how you can debug.

Install node-debug

do node-debug "filename"

This will open in debug mode. Now check how many time the socket.on for 'lock' is being registered. I had similar issue. Heres how i solved it.

```
//check if msgtype is already binded    
if (!isMessageTypeBinded(msgType, someKey)) {
        // emit ot connection
        io.of(someKey).emit(msgType, message)
        return
    } else {
        // apply filter to all connection
        var sockets = io.of(someKey).sockets
        if (msgType) { // check for message tye
            activeMsgConn.push({
                "msgType": msgType,
                "accessKey": someKey
            })
            for (index in sockets) {
                var socket = sockets[index]
                socket.on(msgType, notifyNewMsg(socket))
                io.of(someKey).emit(msgType, message)
            }
        }
    }
```

I am maintianing an array of all the connections made till now.

If a new msg comes, i'll first check if that msg was already binded to the socket and dont add any new namespace. Else i loop thorugh all the socket conneciton and add this handler.

In your case the code need not be same but implementation can be similar.

Comment: I also have a very weird behaviour in my socket.io nodejs chat app,i have sidebar which is filled on "user join" event,and after some time event triiggers at his own,and make double users in sidebar,why thats happen i havent idea,does heroku doing something on server or my bad internet connection doing that.Really weird.